# $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{x+1}{x^2-1}$. Does $f$ have a limit at 1?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

$f:(-1,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{x+1}{x^2-1}$. Does $f$ have a limit at 1?

So, my assumption is obviously that this DNE, because after manipulation and viewing graphically, we see that it does not.

I started out my proof, trying to go by the negation of a limit definition.

$\exists \epsilon>0, \forall \delta>0, 0<|x-x_o|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|\geq\epsilon$.

Where do I go from here? I am having a hard time moving forward with this. I tried towards contradiction, but this will not work algebraically, and also I am a bit uncomfortable doing this sequentially. Just looking for some rationale to help me get through this.

Comment: Use the fact that for $x\neq \pm 1$, $$\frac{x+1}{x^2-1} = \frac{1}{x-1}$$ Then, do this the same way you would show that the limit of $1/x$ does not exist as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

or we get $$\frac{x+1}{(x-1)(x+1)}=\frac{1}{x-1}$$ for $x\neq 1$ and $x\ne -1$

Comment: Sure, I get that - that is what I meant by manipulations. It is clear that limit DNE at 1. Does it suffice to prove that the limit exists everywhere else - a difficult feat unless we break up into sequences.

Answer (score -1):

Assume it does, say, $L$, then for some $\delta>0$ we have if $x\in(1-\delta,1)$ then $|(x+1)/(x^{2}-1)-L|<1$, so for all such $x\in(1-\delta,1)$, $|1/(x-1)-L|<1$, or $1/(1-x)<1+|L|$. Since $1/(1-x)\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 1^{-}$, so $\infty\leq 1+|L|$ as we take limit both sides as $x\rightarrow 1^{-}$.

Comment: Note that if $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in(x_{0}-\delta,x_{0})$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}^{-}}f(x)=L$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}^{-}}g(x)=M$ exist in the extended real sense, we have $L\leq M$.